# Can I get `cabal install` to use multiple cores?

Tags: haskell, build, parallel-processing, cabal, multicore

Does anyone know how to get `cabal install` to exploit parallelism?  I'm compiling with GHC, and while I don't know if GHC itself can do parallel builds, surely `cabal install` could run multiple compilations in parallel, no?  At least for distinct, independent packages?

Does anyone know if it is possible and how to do it?

Comment: What's the motivation for this? Isn't the main bottleneck for cabal the network transfers? Also, couldn't build errors bump into each other, if there are shared dependencies?

Comment: @amindfv: for me, the bottleneck is compiling dozens of haskell source files.   And about dependencies, like parallel make, parallel `cabal install` would have to respect them.  But there is still parallelism available to be had.

Comment: there's also an open [stack issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/644)... (if you're using stack instead of cabal-install)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There was a [Google Summer of Code project this summer](http://dissocial.st/blog/2011-08-22-GSoC-Final) to parallelize `cabal-install`. While it hasn't been merged into the mainline yet, the linked article provides instructions for grabbing the source and building it yourself.

Comment: @donatello: See the update in Mikhail's answer below. I'll see if I can get the link fixed.

Answer (score 51):

I'm the one who was working on this Summer of Code project. The patches have been sent to Duncan, but he hasn't reviewed them yet. Note that my code works at the package granularity, so you won't get any speedup when building a single package. I'm currently working on a [parallel wrapper around `ghc --make`](https://github.com/23Skidoo/ghc-parmake), which will solve this problem (I hope to get it merged into the mainline `cabal-install` eventually).

**Update (Feb. 2012)**: Duncan has reviewed my patches, I need to incorporate his feedback and resubmit them. I hope to get this done before the end of this month.

**Update (Apr. 2012)**: I've [updated my patches](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/ticket/447#comment:8) in response to Duncan's comments. The new code is a bit slower, but requires much less changes to the Cabal library.

**Update (Jun. 2012)**: Duncan Coutts [just merged the parallel branch into Cabal HEAD](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/compare/debd103b69...1185a01d00). Parallel install will be available in the next `cabal-install` release.

**Update (Oct. 2012)**: `cabal-install`1.16.0 [has just been released](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.cabal.devel/9233). This is the first official release that includes my parallel patches.

Comment: That is fantastic! Can you give us a short summary about what the final patch can do? Are normal/profiling compilations parallel? Do single packages now use multiple cores? Thank you.

Comment: And what is the state of `ghc-parmake`?

Comment: @nh2 Maybe I should write a blog post about the current status of parallel install. For now, you can follow the discussion [here](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/976). Short answer: add a line 'jobs: n' (where n is a positive integer) to your `~/.cabal/config`; this makes `cabal install` use n threads. This is only package-level parallelism; modules and components are not built in parallel.

Comment: @nh2 Regarding `ghc-parmake`, it works in some cases, but there are known bugs (can't build libs for profiling, can't build large projects such as uhc, etc). I'm working on another Cabal-related project (sandboxes), so I don't have time to spend on `ghc-parmake` or parallel `cabal build` right now. Maybe after the end of this GSoC.

Comment: I tried the cabal HEAD today (with GHC 7.4.1, and there was a type error, which I solved by deleting code, hehe), and it works pretty well! Will this be in the next Haskell platform?

Comment: If the next Haskell Platform will ship with cabal-install 0.16, then yes.

Comment: @nh2 The next Haskell Platform (2012.4.0.0) will use cabal-install 0.14 and GHC 7.4.2. I expect the 2013.2.0.0 release to ship with cabal-install 1.16 and a more recent GHC.

Comment: Great, looking forward to that!

Comment: With my recent `cabal update`, I got `Note: there is a new version of cabal-install available`, so a `cabal install cabal-install` now gave me 0.16, even on the Haskell Platform 2012.

Answer (score 38):

Completing Mikhail Glushenkov's answer to document the usage a bit:

As of cabal 1.16.0, you can now use

```
cabal install -j [pkgs…]
```

This defaults to one job per core.  It also gives much cleaner output.

You can make parallel installs the default with:

```
echo "jobs: $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)" >> ~/.cabal/config
```

Or (cabal-install 1.18+):

```
echo 'jobs: $ncpus' >> ~/.cabal/config
```

Get the latest cabal-install with:

```
cabal update
cabal install cabal-install --bindir ~/bin --upgrade-dependencies
```

Comment: As of [Cabal 1.18](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/commit/99264248db78835b308232943038e6cbce4e72a4) you can set `jobs` setting to `$ncpus` or a number of jobs to run.